# How to scrape pages after login

Tags: python-2.7, authentication, scrapy

I try to find a way to scrape and parse **more pages** in the **signed in area**.
These example links accesible from signed in I want to parse.

```
#http://example.com/seller/demand/?id=305554
#http://example.com/seller/demand/?id=305553
#http://example.com/seller/demand/?id=305552
#....
```

I want to create spider that can open each one of these links and then parse them.
I have created another spider which can open and parse **only one of them**.

When I tried to create "for" or "while" to call more requests with other links it allowed me not because I cannot put more **returns into generator**, it returns error. I also tried link extractors, but it didn't work for me.

Here is my code:

```
    #!c:/server/www/scrapy
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    from scrapy import Spider
    from scrapy.selector import Selector
    from scrapy.http import FormRequest
    from scrapy.http.request import Request
    from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
    from array import *
    from stack.items import StackItem
    from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

    class Spider3(Spider):
        name = "Spider3"
        allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
        start_urls = ["http://example.com/login"] #this link lead to login page
```

When I am signed in it returns page with url, that contains "stat", that is why I put here first "if" condition.
When I am signed in, I request **one link** and call function parse_items.

```
        def parse(self, response):
                #when "stat" is in url it means that I just signed in
                if "stat" in response.url:              
                    return Request("http://example.com/seller/demand/?id=305554", callback = self.parse_items) 

            else:
                #this succesful login turns me to page, it's url contains "stat"
                return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                        formdata={'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lMain$tbLogin': 'my_login', 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lMain$tbPass': 'my_password'},callback=self.parse)]
```

Function parse_items simply parse desired content from one desired page:

```
        def parse_items(self,response):
                questions = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cRequest_divAll"]/table/tr')
                for question in questions:
                    item = StackItem()
                    item['name'] = question.xpath('th/text()').extract()[0]
                    item['value'] = question.xpath('td/text()').extract()[0]
                    yield item
```

Can you help me please to update this code to open and parse **more than one page** in each sessions? 
I don't want to sign in over and over for each request.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take a minute and read this tutorial for better questions, especially examples about good and bad titles: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - everything else looks good.

Comment: What you need to do here is find next page url and form a requests for it in your `parse_items` method. e.g. `yield Request(next_page, callback=self.parse_items)` . The session most likely depends on the cookies and scrapy manages that by itself. Other than that we can't really help you if you are not providing an url of what you are scraping.

Comment: Are you sure your login is successful?

Comment: yes, login is succesful, I got it.. thank you @Granitosaurus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session most likely depends on the cookies and scrapy manages that by itself. I.e:

```
def parse_items(self,response):
    questions = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cRequest_divAll"]/table/tr')
    for question in questions:
        item = StackItem()
        item['name'] = question.xpath('th/text()').extract()[0]
        item['value'] = question.xpath('td/text()').extract()[0]
        yield item  
    next_url = '' # find url to next page in the current page
    if next_url:
        yield Request(next_url, self.parse_items)
        # scrapy will retain the session for the next page if it's managed by cookies
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on the same problem. I use `InitSpider` so I can overwrite `__init__` and `init_request`. The first is just for initialisation of custom stuff and the actual magic happens in my `init_request`:

```
    def init_request(self):
    """This function is called before crawling starts."""

    # Do not start a request on error,
    # simply return nothing and quit scrapy
    if self.abort:
        return

    # Do a login
    if self.login_required:
        # Start with login first
        return Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)
    else:
        # Start with pase function
        return Request(url=self.base_url, callback=self.parse)
```

My login looks like this

```
def login(self, response):
    """Generate a login request."""

    self.log('Login called')
    return FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata=self.login_data,
        method=self.login_method,
        callback=self.check_login_response
    )
```

`self.login_data` is a `dict` with post values.

I am still a beginner with python and scrapy, so I might be doing it the wrong way. Anyway, so far I have produced a working version that can be viewed on github.

HTH:

https://github.com/cytopia/crawlpy